# Catching fatal errors in C++

Tags: c++, exception

I wrote the following code to detect exceptions but how may I detect and print fatal error to std::cerr?

catch(...) catches all other exceptions but how to reach the error message itself to print it?

```
try {
//Some Code Goes Here
}
catch (MyException &e) {
    to << e.what() << std::endl;
}
catch (...) {
}
```

Comment: `std::cerr` is an output stream, it's not an error itself

Comment: I know that, I want to print to it

Comment: What do you mean by "fatal error"? If you can catch it and handle it, is it really fatal?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `std::exception`

```
try {
//Some Code Goes Here
}
catch (const MyException& e) {
    to << e.what() << std::endl;
}
catch (const std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << e.what();  //<-- catches all other exceptions and print them
}
```

Comment: Don't I need catch(...) for other errors? if not then why they added it to the language

Comment: No, that `std::exception` is already the most generic one

Comment: One more question don't I need to print empty line after the std::cerr << e.what(); ?

Comment: you can, for sure

Comment: This is misleading. You can throw almost anything in C++. Most of those types aren't an std:: exception. Catch(...) Does catch those.

Comment: @MSalters right, `catch(...)` is the real catch all, but then there's no way to print it